# get woocommerce order id and amount for pixel

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been trying to implement a "pixel" for the checkout page in woocommerce on a wordpress site with this:

```
<iframe src="//www.euroads.dk/system/showtrackingpixels.php?cpid=XXXX&sid=1&orderid=%orderid%&currencysymbol=DKK&orderamount=%orderamount%" width=1 height=1 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true" frameborder=0 scrolling=no hspace=0 vspace=0></iframe>
```

I want the %orderid% to get the order id and the %orderamount% to get the total order amount.

i have tried replacing with %orderid% with this

```
<?php echo $order->id ?>
```

and the %orderamount% with this:

```
<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
```

but it doesn't give the correct result. :(

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you really want this pixel on the checkout page? Or the order complete (aka Thank you) page? Either way you current aren't showing how you are defining the `$order` variable so `$order->id` has no value.

Comment: Yes in the very limited instructions, they tell me to put it in the checkout page. I agree with you the it would make more sense to put it on the "Thank You" page.
So you think i have to make some kind of function to define the id and amount to make it work properly or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has got to be the thankyou page as you do not have an order ID assigned on the checkout. Assuming that you could add your pixel tot he `woocommerce_thankyou` hook which is automatically passed the `$order_id` variable.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'so_31783715_pixel' );
function so_31783715_pixel( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_total = $order->get_total();
    printf( "<iframe src="//www.euroads.dk/system/showtrackingpixels.php?cpid=XXXX&sid=1&orderid=%s%&currencysymbol=DKK&orderamount=%s" width=1 height=1 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true" frameborder=0 scrolling=no hspace=0 vspace=0></iframe>", $order_id, $order_total );

}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for. Because I wanted to `localize` a bunch of order variables, the main change I made was to call the `add_action` inside a `wp_enqueue_scripts` func, and make the `woocommerce_thankyou` function inline (`add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', function() {...`), and then threw my `wp_localize_script` inside it. Works like a charm!

Comment: I'm coming back to this almost 7 years later and I have NO idea what I'm talking about in my comment 

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your theme's function file.

Just Update the basic pieces of the pixel so that it will work with your chosen platform's pixel.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////// ADD TO THE END OF YOUR THEME'S FUNCTIONS.PHP FILE ////////////////////////////////////////
if( ! function_exists( 'add_OfferForge_pixel_code' ) )
{
    function add_OfferForge_pixel_code()
    {
        if( is_order_received_page() )
        {
            $oid = "11184";// Offer id - o variable
            $eid = "183";// event id - e variable

            $getid = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
            $uu = explode('/',$getid);
            // if -- ["REQUEST_URI"]=> "/checkout/order-received/1689/?key=wc_order_55c9ee479b4c9"
            $transid = $uu[3];// order id
            $ppppp = $GLOBALS["wp_object_cache"]->cache["post_meta"][$transid]["_order_total"][0]; // price variable with shipping
            echo '<iframe src="https://offerforge.net/p.ashx?o='.$oid.'&e='.$eid.'&t='.$transid.'&p='.$ppppp.'&ect='.$ppppp.'" height="1" width="1" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_OfferForge_pixel_code', 99 );
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I hope this works for you.

I used the order total as the amount for both the r and the ect variables.

** If you are placing an OfferForge pixel you will only need to update the 'oid' and 'eid' values.

Comment: Sorry for double posting.
Thanks for merging my posts Martijn Pieters